# how to get a browser content as a string in blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I want to display the content of any given URL as a string.....
Can any one give some sample code here?

Answer (score 1):

```
        String url = "http://google.com";
    HttpConnection _conn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(url);
    int rc = _conn.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("RC : " + rc);
    if(rc != 200)
        return;


    InputStream is = null;
    byte[] result = null;   
    is = _conn.openInputStream();
    // Get the ContentType
    String type = _conn.getType();


    // Get the length and process the data
    int len = (int)_conn.getLength();
    if (len > 0) {  // If data lenght is defined
        int actual = 0;
        int bytesread = 0;
        result = new byte[len];
        while ((bytesread != len) && (actual != -1)) {
            actual = is.read(result, bytesread, len - bytesread);
            bytesread += actual;
        }
    }else { // If no data lenght is not defined in HTTP response
        // Data accumulation buffer (for whole data)
        NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new NoCopyByteArrayOutputStream(1024);
        // Receive buffer (for each portion of data)
        byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
        while ((len = is.read(buff)) > 0) {
            // Write received portion of data into accumulation stream
            outputStream.write(buff, 0, len);
        }
        result = outputStream.toByteArray();
        System.out.println(new String(result));
    }
```